# Create mutli-page document dynamically using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am attempting to create a PDF report from a Java ResultSet.  If the report was only one page, I would have no problem here.  The issue comes from the fact that the report could be anywhere from one to ten pages long.  Right now, I have this to create a single-page document:

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_LETTER);
document.addPage(page);
PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(document,page);
```

So my question is, how do I create pages dynamically as they are needed.  Is there an object-oriented answer staring me in the face and I just cannot see it?

Comment: What is so bad (in the context of the very low-level PDFBox page creation API) about `page = new PDPage`, `document.addPage(page)`, and `content = new PDPageContentStream` each time your current page is full?

Comment: @mkl, yes, thank you!  As I expected, the answer was lying right under my nose.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As I expected, the answer was staring me right in the face, I just needed someone to point it out for me.

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_LETTER);
document.addPage(page);
PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(document,page);

//generate data for first page

content.close();

//if number of results exceeds what can fit on the first page
page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_LETTER);
document.addPage(page);
content = new PDPageContentStream(document,page);

//generate data for second page

content.close();
```

Thanks to @mkl for the answer.

Comment: could you please specify how to know "if the number of results exceeeds what can fit on the first page"? thanks

Comment: When using this example I got a warning
"pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.<init>: You are overwriting an existing content, you should use the append mode" and only the last page of PDF was written to the file".

I resolved it using the constructor with 2 boolean parameters:
content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, true, true);

Comment: As of PDFBox 2.0.20 the constants for the page sizes are in the `PDRectangle` class now. So creating a new page would be done with `PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.LETTER);`

Answer (score 10):

**To Create Multi Page PDF Document using PDFBox:**

(a) Create new page, new content stream, Move to Top Left, start writing. While writing each word check whether space required is not crossing mediabox width. If crosses, move to next line leftmost and start writing. Continue writing till the last line of the page.
(b) Close the contentStream and add the current page to the document when the writing operation reaches the last line of the current page,
(c) Repeat steps (a) and (b) till the last record/row/line is written.

```
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;

//For Each Page:
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4);
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
        contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 700);
        contentStream.drawString("PDF BOX TEXT CONTENT");
        contentStream.endText();
        contentStream.close();
        document.addPage(page);

//After All Content is written:
        document.save(pdfFile);
        document.close();
```

**Hint:** Use Font parameters like size/height and remaining media box height to determine the last line of the page.